# losing session whe modifying directory in .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

A site I work on allows users to upload their own images and other resources.

User can copy the default resources folder (images + css) to a new folder. They can then overwrite the resources with their own versions and the system will use this folder rather than the default.

Any new images are also saved as bytes to a database.

There is a function to synchronise these resources, at which point the new images folder is deleted, the default is then copied over again and any images stored in the db are then recreated and overwrite the applicable images in the new folder.

Occasionally this causes application_end to be called and all users are logged out. I have noticed this pattern:

If it fails it does so after the new images folder is deleted, but before the new folder is copied. The next time round it generally works - but this time it has no folder in new to delete as it wasn't recreated last time.

I noticed this somewhere on the web to do with app pool recycles.

•   The number of re-compilations (aspx, ascx or asax) exceeds the limit specified by the setting in machine.config or web.config (by default this is set to 15)

Would what i am doing cause this? Perhaps because the second time it doesn't have to delete it doesnt exceed the limit of file chnages?

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

Comment: Where are the resources located? `~/Resources/`?

Comment: Yes but it was a bit vague. Updating the .aspx files, etc. Does etc include images?

Comment: the default resources are at ~/Content/default/images

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the directory being deleted, As a solution I used reflection to turn off the fileactivitymonitor whilst running this fucntion, then turned it on again afterwards